# Grid com loop quebra no wordpress! Uso Foundation6 como framework

Tags: wordpress-theme, grid, zurb-foundation

Boa tarde, venho tendo muitos problemas ao fazer um grid com loop, como os posts de um blog em grid, segue uma imagem de ilustração: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeFI5.png

Alguém sabe o que fazer para o grid não quebrar?
Segue o código:

```
<!-- the loop -->           
        <?php while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>

          <article class="loop large-6 columns text-center">
            <div class="img-post"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-large', array( 'alt' => get_the_title(), 'title' => get_the_title() ) ); ?></a></div><br>
            <div class="titulo-post medium-11 medium-centered"><h2><strong><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></strong></h2></div>             
            <div class="content medium-10 medium-centered text-justify">
              <!--?php the_excerpt(); ?-->
              <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><div class="text-center"><button class="button">LEIA MAIS</button></a></div><br><br><br>
          </article>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <!-- end of the loop -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Você tem algumas maneiras de fazer isso. Usando um plugin de grid tipo [esse](https://troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/)

Se as grid tiverem sempre o mesmo tamanho, você pode colocar uma altura fixa.
No código que você colocou sentir falta de uma div com a class 'row' pra fazer as linhas. Ela também é importante como você pode ver [aqui](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/grid.html)